# Quelles seraient d’autres façons de dire « calmer le jeu » en parlant de diminuer un conflit ?

Tags: vocabulaire, formulation-idiomatique, synonymes, formulation, reformulation

En parlant d’un conflit/d’une bisbille/de tensions dans une boîte de nuit dont l’on veut éviter l’escalade.

Je vais chercher, par tous les moyens, à calmer le jeu.

Comment: Ça peut dépendre du genre de conflit, en l'état c'est un peu vgue.

Comment: Ca depend du contexte: s'il s'agit des enfants qui chamaillent, d'une engueulade au supermarché, du conflict au travail, de la bataille publique entre politiciens ou de la guerre en Ukraine.

Comment: Dans la plupart si ce n'est tous les cas, *calmer le jeu* marche très bien. Pourquoi vouloir autre chose ?

Comment: @jlliagre Certains ne connaissent pas la signification de cette expression et je me vois obliger de reformuler mon propos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Je vais chercher, par tous les moyens, à **apaiser** l'atmosphère.*